# Setting Parameters in CI4s redirecting function

Tags: php, codeigniter-4

is there any possible way to send parameters within the redirection function from Codeigniter 4?
Important, it is a named route:

```
$routes->get('edit', 'Test_Controller::editTest/$1', ["as" => "editTest", "filter" => 'testFilter']);
```

And i want to do a redirect like this:

this works fine:

```
return $this->redirectTo('test/edit/' . $id1);
```

this would be nice, if it works:

```
return redirect('editTest', array($passingID));
```

or

```
return redirect('editTest')->with($passingID);
```

Why? I have HMVC and I would like to name every module with the same routes but different functions ofc. And this would help me having same site urls. (edit, add, a.s.o.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is no its not possible. Take a look at `system/Common.php` and you'll see there is only 1 parameter to the `redirect()` function.

The longer answer however is take a look at what the redirect function does.

```
function redirect(?string $route = null): RedirectResponse
    {
    $response = Services::redirectresponse(null, true);

    if (! empty($route)) {
        return $response->route($route);
    }

    return $response;
}
```

Based on the current (4.1.4) redirect function you'll see it calls `route()`.  It turns out that route() allows a second parameter which are the parameters.

So the solution would probably be to do your own redirect() function (see https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/extending/common.html?highlight=common) and allow a second parameter.